# Cómo encontrar el valor par más grande de cada fila y el valor impar más pequeño de cada columna

Tags: c, matrices

Estoy trabajando en DevC++, y me han pedido que encuentre el elemento par más grande de cada fila y el valor impar más pequeño de cada columna de una matriz de 5x5. He intentado algo que me parecía lógico, pero que a la hora de correr el ejecutable no hace lo que se requiere. A continuación presento mi código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    printf("\n Matriz:\n");
        //En esta parte ya he llenado la matriz, ya sólo estoy mostrándola.
        for (int i = 0; i < fil; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                printf("%d\t", matriz[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
```

Aquí ya empieza la parte en donde presento el problema:

```
        printf("\nVALORES IMPARES CHICOS DE CADA COLUMNA:\n");
        for (int i=0;i<fil;i++)
        {
            min=matriz[0][i];
            for (int j=0;j<col;j++)
            {
                /*Esto es lo que según yo intenté para que evaluara si era par 
                y a su vez que evaluara cada valor de cada columna.*/

                if((matriz[i][j]%2!=0)&&(matriz[j][i]<min))
                {
                    min=matriz[j][i];
                }
            }
            printf("%d\t",min);
        }
        printf("\n");
        
        //Para las filas aún no hago la evaluación de las columnas.
        printf("\nVALORES PARES CHICOS DE CADA FILA:\n");
        for (int j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            min2=matriz[j][0];
            for (int i=0;i<fil;i++)
            {
                if(matriz[j][i]<min2)
                {
                    min2=matriz[j][i];
                }
            }
            printf("%d\t",min2);
        }
}
```

Entonces quisiera saber cómo es que puedo encontrar estos valores, ya que soy nuevo en esto y no he dado con ninguna.

Comment: ¿Cómo estás llenando la matriz? Una solución óptima pero con un contra de memoria sería tener dos arreglos con una capacidad igual al número de columnas de tu matriz. Cada que ingresas un número vas guardando en uno de los arreglos el valor más grande y en otro el más pequeño.

Comment: @Jacobo La forma de llenar mi matriz es muy revuelta, por eso no la puse y sólo aclaré que ya la había llenado. Y muchas gracias por tu ayuda. ¡Feliz año nuevo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que llevas hasta ahora está bien, entiendo lo que tratas de hacer con los `for` para recorrer la matriz, me parece un buen método, sin embargo, tienes unos cuantos problemas.

**1. Tienes incongruencias en tus condiciones**

Esto está mal:

```
if((matriz[i][j]%2!=0)&&(matriz[j][i]<min))
```

Debería de ser consistente, así:

```
if((matriz[i][j]%2!=0)&&(matriz[i][j]<min))
```

**2. La manera en la que inicializas las variables que alojan los resultados (`min` y `min2`)**

Mira lo que haces cuando estás buscando los valores chicos impares de cada columna:

Inicializas la variable donde guardas los resultados así:

```
min=matriz[0][i];
```

Utilizando como condición:

```
if((matriz[i][j]%2!=0)&&(matriz[i][j]<min))
```

El primer problema es del lado de la paridad(`matriz[i][j]%2!=0`)... Asumes que el primer valor de cada columna es impar y lo asignas a la variable `min`, lo cual sería incorrecto, si por ejemplo tu matriz fuese algo como:

```
2 2 2
4 6 8
8 8 6
```

Obtendrías que los valores impares chicos de cada columna serían 2 porque no existen más valores impares en la matriz, por lo tanto se asume que es valor con el cual inicializaste la variable `min`, lo cuál a final de cuentas no es cierto.

El segundo problema es del lado del valor mínimo (`matriz[i][j]<min`)... Si el primer valor de cada columna fuese cero, no importa si los demás números son impares... Siempre vas a tener como resultado final 0 para cada columna. Es decir, una matriz así:

```
0 0 0
3 7 9
1 9 3
```

Daría como resultado 0 para cada columna, lo cuál no es cierto, esto debido a que `matriz[i][j]<min` nunca se cumpliría debido a que hiciste `min=matriz[0][i];`.

**3. Necesitas una manera para indicar que no existe un valor par o impar en tu resultado**

No importa como inicialices `min` o `min2` siempre vas a tener el problema de que tu código no tiene manera de checkear si realmente se encontró el resultado esperado.

**4. La manera en la que recorres tu array (sugerencia)**

Si quieres recorrer columnas:

```
 for (int j=0;j<col;j++)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<fil;i++)
        {
            valor=matriz[i][j];
```

Si quieres recorrer filas:

```
 for (int i=0;i<fil;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            valor=matriz[i][j];
```

Te recomiendo que no hagas esto:

```
matriz[j][i];
```

Sé congruente con tu código, define por ejemplo `i` para filas y `j` para columnas y sigue ese orden. Por lo tanto, siempre usa:

```
matriz[i][j];
```

### Mi sugerencia:

Utiliza un valor muy grande para inicializar tus variables de resultado (`min` y `min2`), de está manera te garantizas de que siempre vas a encontrar un valor menor... De paso puedes utilizar este valor gigante para comprobar si efectivamente se encontró un resultado. Esto no es la manera óptima de hacerlo, lo que quiero es que tengas una idea de cómo corregir tu código.

Realizando las correcciones y utilizando la matriz de prueba:

```
7 4 3
8 2 5
3 6 7
```

Tu código (solo la parte de la imparidad en columnas) podría verse algo así:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TAMANO_FILA 3
#define TAMANO_COLUMNA 3

int VALOR_MAXIMO = 99999999;
int matriz[TAMANO_FILA][TAMANO_COLUMNA] = {
        {7,4,3},
        {8,2,5},
        {3,6,7}
    };
int min =0;
int min2 =0;

int main()
{
    
    
    printf("\nVALORES IMPARES CHICOS DE CADA COLUMNA:\n");
        for (int j=0;j<TAMANO_COLUMNA;j++)
        {
            min=VALOR_MAXIMO;
            for (int i=0;i<TAMANO_FILA;i++)
            {
                if((matriz[i][j]%2!=0)&&(matriz[i][j]<min))
                {
                    min=matriz[i][j];
                }
            }
            if(min==VALOR_MAXIMO){
              printf("NA\t");
            }else{
               printf("%d\t",min);  
            }
            
            
        }
        printf("\n");
        

    return 0;
}
```

Mira que tomé como valor máximo `99999999`, esto significa que es un requisito que los valores de la matriz sean menores que esto. Puedes cambiar esto de muchas maneras, solo quiero ilustrar como corregir uno de los problemas que tienes.

Resultado final:

```
VALORES IMPARES CHICOS DE CADA COLUMNA:
3   NA  3
```

NA= No hay resultado

Comment: Hombre, pues muchísimas gracias, en serio no sabes cuánto me has ayudado, y no sólo me has dado la respuesta, sino que me has dicho en qué cosas estaba mal. Te lo agradezco mucho. ¡Feliz año nuevo!